# wget download multiple FILES not URLS from file on same site

Tags: python

When i trying to do that:

```
os.system("xargs -i wget 'http://{}'  < out.txt")
```

I got error:

```
xargs: wget: No such file or directory
```

But file out.txt exist in directory. and showing output on this command:

os.system("cat out.txt")

So how to download multiple FILES not URLS from file on same site with wget.

Comment: You'd need to [subclass the control](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Subclassing) and paint it yourself. This is *not* a trivial task to say the least. I'd suggest starting by looking for a third-party ActiveX control that supports the functionality you need.